# Is there a better way to write this jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have the following line of jQuery but it seems like overkill to use `.each()`.

```
$('span[data-private]').each(function () { 
    $(this).text($(this).attr("data-hidden")); 
});
```

Is there a better way to write this jQuery that would look something like:

```
// This doesn't work as $(this) refers to document not the current selector
// but it gives the idea of what I'm looking for.  I want to reference the current
// selector
$('span[data-private]').text($(this).attr("data-hidden"));
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Need some context, on what event should this happen...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `each()` method should be used when you are looping through elements. If you have several elements to apply this function to then use this:

```
$('span[data-private]').each(function () { 
    $(this).text($(this).attr("data-hidden")); 
});
```

Alternatively, if you are only applying this function to one element, then just use the callback on the `text()` method like so:

```
$('span[data-private]').text(function () { 
    return $(this).attr("data-hidden"); 
});
```

**Neither of the two methods are taxing in anyway, however, this method is slightly slightly less taxing as it does not loop through elements**

Comment: And I eat bananas, doesn't mean _everyone_ should

Comment: @Neal What I mean is, I have never noticed any lag in performance from using it. It is a great function and in this case it is necessary!

Comment: it's a loop, it's a bunch of actions that fire one after the other, if you can save the extra operations might as well optimize because later when your code has turned into a full fledged library or something you'll be glad you've been saving operations the whole time...

Comment: You're using redundant code ... your second code example reads: Set the text property of the element to the return value of the anonymous function which itself sets the text property and returns nothing. This should be the correct line inside the anonymous function of your second code example: `return $(this).attr('data-hidden')`

Comment: @devnull69 Thank you for the correction, I copied and pasted the code from my first example and forgot to correct it

Answer (score 2):

[`.text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) can be passed a callback function.

```
$('span[data-private]').text(function(){
    return $(this).attr("data-hidden");
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/9w69E/

Comment: Is this any less taxing than just using .each() ?

Comment: @RHarris neither are **really** that ***taxing***

Comment: @RHarris: What do you mean by "taxing"?  I wouldn't worry too much about performance.

Comment: @Rocket Taxing was probably the wrong word.  What I mean is, the code doesn't look any more terse or tight than just using each.  I was basically looking to simplify the code if possible.  (Not that it was extremely complex to begin with).  Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm maybe try something like this:

```
(function(){
    var $self = $('span[data-private]');
    $self.text($self.data('hidden'));
})()
```

Comment: Will this loop through all of the elements? Why is it better than the `each()` method?

Comment: @BenCarey this ***won't*** loop through anything.

Comment: Exactly! Does RHarris not want to apply this to all elements, or is there only one? **We do not know!!!**